# How to work out width and height of multined string with font?

Tags: c++, c, winapi, gdi

My program draws text strings into rectangles by working out the width and height of the text, and selecting a smaller font if its too big for the rectangle. But originally i only used single lined text, now i need some multi lined, i used to use [GetTextExtentPoint32](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144938%28VS.85%29.aspx) but if theres \n in the string, it seems to think of that as a normal character.

[DrawText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162498%28VS.85%29.aspx) with DT_CALCRECT only returns the height of the text...

Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: You can't make the font smaller forever or it will be unreadable.    So eventually you will have to add a scroll bar, or a More... button, or some other way to deal with it.  Since you have to do that anyway, playing with the font size seems like a high-cost/low-payback activity.  Unless, of course, the customer demands the requirement and you are being paid by the hour.

Comment: I load 20 HFONT at the apps creation, the smallest is 5 height, if no font fits in the rectangle out of those it draws none :P and surprisingly the performance is great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docs for [DrawText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162498(v=vs.85).aspx) state that while it only returns the height, it *modifies the rectangle* you pass it. Are you checking the rectangle, or only the return value? It sounds like you would actually want to pass in a rectangle with a large width (ie. maximum width you want to allow), and DrawText will reduce as necessary. (If you pass in a small width, it will expand it only enough to fit the largest word.)

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162498(v=vs.85).aspx):

> If there are multiple lines of text, DrawText uses the width of the rectangle pointed to by the lpRect parameter and extends the base of the rectangle to bound the last line of text. If the largest word is wider than the rectangle, the width is expanded.

Answer (score 1):

You should do roughly this (pseudo code):

```
size text_dim(0,0);
foreach( line in text.split("\n") )
{
  size line_dim = GetTextExtentPoint32(line.start,line.length);
  text_dim.y += line_dim.y;
  text_dim.x = max(text_dim.x,line_dim.x);
}
return text_dim;
```